# Base table or view not found: 1146 Table '.catalog_product_entity_boolean' doesn't exist

Tags: magento2

After updating to magento 2.3.0 experienced an error on the store frontend.

> Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
>   '.catalog_product_entity_boolean' doesn't exist.

Comment: Magento don't provide any table like this, do one thing,
remove var , pub/static, generated folder. and run upgrade and compile command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the following queries and add `catalog_product_entity_boolean` table

```
        CREATE TABLE catalog_product_entity_boolean (
         value_id int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Value ID',
         attribute_id smallint(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Attribute ID',
         store_id smallint(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Store ID',
         entity_id int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
         value int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Value'
        ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Catalog Product Integer Attribute Backend Table';

        --
        -- Indexes for table catalog_product_entity_boolean
        --
        ALTER TABLE catalog_product_entity_boolean
         ADD PRIMARY KEY (value_id),
         ADD UNIQUE KEY catalog_product_entity_boolean_ENTITY_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID_STORE_ID (entity_id,attribute_id,store_id),
         ADD KEY catalog_product_entity_boolean_ATTRIBUTE_ID (attribute_id),
         ADD KEY catalog_product_entity_boolean_STORE_ID (store_id);

        --
        -- AUTO_INCREMENT for table catalog_product_entity_boolean
        --
        ALTER TABLE catalog_product_entity_boolean
         MODIFY value_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Value ID';

        --
        -- Constraints for table catalog_product_entity_boolean
        --
        ALTER TABLE catalog_product_entity_boolean
         ADD CONSTRAINT catalog_product_entity_boolean_STORE_ID_STORE_STORE_ID FOREIGN KEY (store_id) REFERENCES store (store_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
         ADD CONSTRAINT CAT_PRD_ENTT_INT_ATTR_ID_EAV_ATTR_ATTR_ID FOREIGN KEY (attribute_id) REFERENCES eav_attribute (attribute_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
         ADD CONSTRAINT CAT_PRD_ENTT_INT_ENTT_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID FOREIGN KEY (entity_id) REFERENCES catalog_product_entity (entity_id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a custom attribute that was programatically created with a backend type of boolean. If you look in the `eav_attribute` table, there will be a row with a `backend_type` of `boolean`. Change it to `int`.